# How to get any kind of interactive plot with ipywidgets and matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am just looking for some kind of working example which will allow me to have a slider and a sine wave plot whereby I can vary the frequency in a Jupyter Notebook.  All the online demos that I have Googled don't work for me.  The issue seems to be that the old matplotlib graph is not erased before the new one is created.

Here is my minimal example

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(a):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(a*x)
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel("y")
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_title("y = sin(x)")

%matplotlib inline
from time import sleep
for i in range(1,10):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    f(i)
    sleep(1)
```

I have also tried

```
out = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
with out:
    widgets.interact(f, a=1)
    out.clear_output()
    display(out)
```

However nothing I try will erase the previous matplotlib graph.  They just all pile up on top of each other.  I admit I am floundering as I don't really understand the API that well and the example in the documentation don't work for me.

I don't expect people to fix my code as it is probably rubbish.  I am just looking for a working example which will allow me to interactively control the frequency and redraw the sine wave on a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimal example that works for me:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widgets

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot(freq):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
    y = np.sin(x * freq)
    plt.plot(x, y)

interact(plot, freq = widgets.FloatSlider(value=2, min=0.1, max=5, step=0.1))
```

default plot:

[image: default]

Screenshot of notebook after moving the slider to the right:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When I do that I don't even get a slider and I am using the official  jupyter/scipy-notebook docker image. https://ibb.co/gwHZWpR

Comment: Have you properly installed and activated ipywidgets? In your shell, run `pip install ipywidgets` and `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`.

Comment: The widgets will display using the RangeSliders but just not via interact

Comment: it plots below the previous plot each time